# Using the MVC design pattern, where to store JSON data that a model communicates with?

Tags: php, json, model-view-controller, model

edit: apparently it's too late to delete this question, which is a shame because I have no idea why storing pages in a JSON file seemed like a reasonable idea last May.

---

It'd be good to let a framework handle page routing instead of reinventing the wheel, but I'm trying to understand actual implementation of this design pattern better as much as anything else. I also recognize that [a pure implementation of MVC may not always be possible for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516771/1624318), but all of this is server-side.

This is my current structure (minus irrelevant files):

```
app/
    controllers/
        PageController.php

    models/
        PageModel.php

    views/
        GlobalFooter.php
        GlobalHeader.php

    Pages.json

config/
    db_connect.php

/docs
/lib
/web
    /js
    /img
    /css
    index.php
```

When a user loads a page, the page instantiates a controller which passes the $_GET parameter to the page model.

The model loads the Pages.JSON file as an associative array and retrieves specific page data:

```
title
controller
page-specific stylesheet names
page-specific script names
which membergroups can access it
etc.
```

Along with extracting a dynamic list of the pages this User is allowed to access, for navigation. The controller then calls the appropriate view with the appropriate content.

**So far:** Originally I was going to put the Pages.json in with the "views", because it's static data and the stylesheet/script specification is relevant to front-end management. After all, the goal is that repainting the house only needs webroot access, or views template access for more extensive remodeling.

But Pages.json is not a view. It's a data source.

**Current "solution":**
Leaving the file on the top level in app/...but I feel like this is an MVC faux pas.

Even if it isn't, I don't want my app folder to become a dumping ground for data sources.

**Potential solutions I've been tossing around:**

1. Storing the pages in a database table instead of JSON and having a PageModel method call a method from *db_connect.php* to fetch it. But I want pages to be able to load skeletons of themselves even if a connection to the database fails. Additionally, even with cacheing, I don't want to make that database request whenever a page loads.
2. Storing the pages in a multidimensional PHP array instead of JSON...but then I have the same design problem, albeit with a PHP file, something I want working on the front end of this to touch even less than JSON. Along with a teeny bit more overhead.
3. Adding *data/* as a data-housing directory in *app/*...but this also feels too much like stepping outside the design pattern and creating a dumping ground.
4. Going back to separate parallel one-dimensional PHP arrays in the PageModel, which might theoretically be more efficient, but it was ugly and risky and hard-coded compared to sourcing page info dynamically. Nah.

**Current planned solution:**

1. Decoupling the front-end JSON data (stylesheet, etc.) from the
   back-end (controller, etc.) into two JSON files.
2. Storing front-end data sources in views/ from now on.
3. Storing back-end ones in model/ from now on.

Does that sound like a good solution? Or is there a convention already for where data sources should be stored?

*Or* is this an X question for a Y problem and I shouldn't be storing the pages as JSON data at all? And if so, what would be a better alternative to either that, database tables, or hard-coded PHP arrays?

If anyone has advice or an answer, thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid storing these values in a json file.

1. you can introduce a naming convention, which might not be a good
   solution for some use cases.
2. I would tie CSS and JSS in the template file (HTML or PHP) file on
   your view. this way you dont have to list all your assets files
   manually in a json file. Thus your designer/frontend programmer can
   just write a "normal" HTML/template/PHP file.
3. Having a model that loads page definition, might cause a problem when you have 2 or models in your page. And also your model will not be reusable, because it's tied to a page.
4. For your page definition, such as title, meta keywords and stuff, you can create 1 model specifically for this. Your controller then fetch these data by calling it for a specified action/page. e.g. in index action, you can call: pageDefModel->getMetaTags();. then you can pass these results to your view.